# Use Persist Session in Meteor

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

Recently, I am working with Meteor.js and the problem arise from my development is how to use persist session for Meteor.js.

I have worked with Meteor session and it removed when I am refresh the site. So I realized I need to do something for my session.

I have worked with google and all of them I found out about the persist session is using localStorage.

If I use localStorage, my session should not been working on IE because IE doesn't support localStorage.

Is there any suggestion for my problem?
Thanks for your kind attention.

Comment: Local storage works on IE 11+. https://caniuse.com/#search=local%20storage

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ground db](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/ground-db) which also allows you client side offline content and thus makes your session data persistent on your users devices. This comes in handy if you want to have your clients manage the persistence storage while still being able to manage complex sets of data caching.

If this does not suit your needs, you could create a collection that acts as your session. The advantage is here that persistence is kept beyond client influence on the server. The hurdle is, that you need to implement a steady session-get-set mechanism with lots of Method calls and data updates.

A schema for this session could be:

```
{
  userId:String, 
  state:{
    type:Object,
    backbox:true,
  }
}
```

The [blackbox](https://github.com/longshotlabs/simpl-schema#blackbox) attribute allows you to bypass validation and make this collection very flexible for use as session storage. Disadvantage is that it can create a security flaw because the incoming data is not validated by collection2-core (if you use it). You have to validate your variables yourself then.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer @Jankapunkt's approach, but just to put it out there, there is [this **unsupported** package](https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session) that does the job of persisting session variables over browser refreshes.

Eg: Session.set(key, value)